# Сортировка массива String по количеству заглавных букв

Tags: java, массивы, строки, сортировка

Есть массив String, нужно отсортировать по возрастанию количества заглавных букв в строках. Как это сделать ? Желательно без компаратора, ибо пока что не понимаю, как им пользоваться.

```java
String[] names = {"DeaaaSaaaAaAAAan", "DeaWeWEaan",
        "DeaaFDfaaaaaan", "DeWan", "DeaaaaSaan",
        "DeaSLKDan", "Deaaaaaaaaan", "Deaaaan", "Deaaaaan"};
```

Comment: `Желательно без компаратора` желательно понять, что это и зачем, вам же это упростит жизнь.

Comment: Я понимаю, что он полезный, просто сейчас нужно именно без него.

Comment: Вы мозете написать метод, который принимает 2 строки и возвращает -1, если первая строка меньше, 1 если первая строка больше и 0 если строки равны согласно вашей задаче?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если без компаратора это будет сортировка через циклы. Однако оставлю [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5393307/7540461) на сортировку с `Comparator`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"DeaaaSaaaAaAAAan", "DeaWeWEaan",
            "DeaaFDfaaaaaan", "DeWan", "DeaaaaSaan",
            "DeaSLKDan", "Deaaaaaaaaan", "Deaaaan", "Deaaaaan"};

    //сортируем
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        String temp = "";
        for (int j = i + 1; j < names.length; j++) {
            //условие сортировки
            if (countUpperCase(names[i]) > countUpperCase(names[j])) {
                temp = names[i];
                names[i] = names[j];
                names[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //вывод
    System.out.println("now: " + Arrays.toString(names));
}

//получаем кол-во заглавных букв в тексте 
private static long countUpperCase(String inputString) {
    return inputString.chars().filter((s) -> Character.isUpperCase(s)).count();
}
```

`countUpperCase` тоже можно сделать через цикл (но зачем)

Comment: Хотя ваш код и работает, я бы отметил, что циклы (или сортировка пузырьком) - не единственный способ сортировки без компаратора.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью метода [`Arrays.sort(T[],Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)) сортируем элементы массива. Для каждого элемента считаем количество заглавных букв и передаём в метод [`Comparator.comparingLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-):

```java
String[] names = {"DeaaaSaaaAaAAAan", "DeaWeWEaan",
        "DeaaFDfaaaaaan", "DeWan", "DeaaaaSaan",
        "DeaSLKDan", "Deaaaaaaaaan", "Deaaaan", "Deaaaaan"};

// сортируем массив по количеству заглавных букв
Arrays.sort(names, Comparator.comparingLong(str -> str
        // получаем IntStream по символам строки
        .chars()
        // отбираем только заглавные буквы
        .filter(Character::isUpperCase)
        // считаем количество
        .count()));

Arrays.stream(names).forEach(System.out::println);
// Deaaaaaaaaan
// Deaaaan
// Deaaaaan
// DeWan
// DeaaaaSaan
// DeaaFDfaaaaaan
// DeaWeWEaan
// DeaSLKDan
// DeaaaSaaaAaAAAan
```